# How do I make my jquery loading spinner automatic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner, loading, gif

I used a JQuery waiting spinner demo from Github and modified it to my liking. I want the spinner to initiate automatically as soon as the page appears (giving time for the larger images on the page to load), however at the moment one has to click 'start waiting' for the spinner to appear.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="waiting.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">
body {
margin: 50px;
}
.content {
margin-bottom: 50px;
max-width: 500px;
}
button.waiting-done {
display: none;
}
</style>


<!--script src="../libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script-->
<script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src=" jquery.waiting.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var content = $('.content').first().html();
$('button').on('click', function () {
$(this).toggle().siblings('button').toggle();

if ($(this).hasClass('waiting-done')) {
$(this).siblings('.content').waiting('done')
.html(content.substring(0,Math.random() * content.length) + '...');
}
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="demo-fixed">
><button type="button" class="waiting">► start waiting</button>
><button type="button" class="waiting-done">■ waiting done</button>

<div class="content">
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#demo-fixed button.waiting').on('click', function () {
var that = this;
$(this).siblings('.content').waiting({ fixed: true });
setTimeout(function() {
$(that).siblings('button').click();
}, 3000);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my first post so I hope I've given enough info for people to understand. I could copy the JQuery but there's too much and i'm not sure on the relevant part.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice tool built in for that -- you'll want to read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
//start spinner 
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
//stop spinner 
});


$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXhr, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
// handle the error
});
```